# Unable to create home directories

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, home

For a school assignment our team has been provided a VM from the school. We were handed the VM with our user accounts added to the sudo group, and I also have access to the "root" and "sysadm" accounts that already exist on the machine, presumably from the sysadmin that did the setup.

I noticed an issue: I am unable to create any directories or files in the home directory.

```
411blackf16:/> ls -lashr
total 93K
   0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     29 Sep  8 07:43 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
   0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     29 Sep  8 18:35 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  14 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:16 var
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  10 root   root   4.0K Sep  8 07:42 usr
4.0K drwxrwxrwt  10 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:44 tmp
4.0K drwx------   2 sysadm sysadm 4.0K Sep 12 18:44 sysadm
   0 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root   root      0 Sep 12 18:30 sys
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Apr 20 18:08 srv
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Apr 19 10:31 snap
 12K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    12K Sep 12 13:18 sbin
   0 drwxr-xr-x  36 root   root   1.4K Sep 12 18:32 run
4.0K drwx------   3 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:34 root
   0 dr-xr-xr-x 219 root   root      0 Sep  8 23:42 proc
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 12:20 opt
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Apr 20 18:08 mnt
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root   4.0K Sep  8 07:42 media
 16K drwx------   2 root   root    16K Sep  8 07:42 lost+found
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Sep  8 07:42 lib64
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  22 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:22 lib
   0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     32 Sep  8 07:43 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
   0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     32 Sep  8 18:35 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
   0 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root      0 Sep 12 19:03 home
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 106 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:56 etc
   0 drwxr-xr-x  19 root   root   4.2K Sep  8 23:43 dev
1.0K drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root   1.0K Sep 12 13:19 boot
4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 13:18 bin
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:51 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root   4.0K Sep 12 18:51 .
```

The owner is root:root.

```
411blackf16:/> sudo mkdir /home/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/test’: Permission denied
411blackf16:/> sudo su root
root@411blackf16:/# sudo mkdir /home/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/test’: Permission denied
```

Using my sudo user account or the root account still doesn't allow creation of directory or files.

```
root@411blackf16:/# chmod -R 777 /home/ && touch /home/test
touch: cannot touch '/home/test': Permission denied
```

Even opening up the permissions doesn't help. Does anyone have some any idea on what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `lsattr /home` please?

Comment: @ByteCommander lsattr /home provides no output.

Comment: have you tried,  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/

Comment: @CJDana, that's a **really** bad idea.  **Don't** run that command.

Comment: @CJDana changing ownership or permissions doesn't work. The issue is that /home is mounted without write permissions as part of the school's ldap/non-standard image configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

- `/home` could be a filesystem which is mounted readonly (the `mount` command would show you this)
- as an exercise, your instructor *could* have set some interesting ACL (but then `ls` should have shown a `.` or other punctuation character after the permissions)
- the VM (underlying file) permissions are readonly, and the machine cannot write-through its changes (so for instance, journalling might have died).

In a followup, OP showed the results from `mount`:

```
411blackf16:/> mount | grep home
ldap:CN=auto.home,OU=Unix Autofs,DC=cs,DC=odu,DC=edu on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=1415,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=‌​5,indirect)
```

and MikeA pointed out that

- the *type* is `"autofs"`, which shows that the filesystem is mounted, and
- the string `"ldap:CN=auto.home,OU=Unix Autofs,DC=cs,DC=odu,DC=edu"` indicates that it is mounted using LDAP credentials.
- all of this implies that the actual `/home` is on another machine that OP cannot modify (aside from files in his/her home-directory).

The **`root`** user on the VM would not have any permissions on this filesystem (it would be treated as **`nobody`**).

If you want to create local user accounts in the VM, with a local home directory, you can put their home directory in a different location. `/home` is a very common convention, but not an absolute rule.

Further reading:

- [13.2.7. Configuring Services: autofs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-ldap-autofs.html)

Comment: `/home` could also be NFS mounted and the VM does not have write permission to the remote resource

Comment: 411blackf16:/> mount | grep home
ldap:CN=auto.home,OU=Unix Autofs,DC=cs,DC=odu,DC=edu on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=1415,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)

Comment: re @mikea - sure, the point is that either the VM is treating `/home` as readonly, or the VM cannot write to a supposedly writable filesystem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Are you able to discern anything from mount output? It appears to be a rw device but this is really outside of my domain and prior knowledge.

Comment: your `/home` is getting mounted through autofs using a map in ldap.  you won't be able to create home directories in `/home`.  they have to be created on some other source and added to the automount map to show up in `/home` on your vm.  you should add the info from your comment to the original post.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll do some looking into how we can revert back to a standard /home configuration.

Comment: @MikeA The thing I don't understand is that I have a home directory I use on the standard machines the school provides but in this case none of the home directories are being included on our VM , although we are using the same ldap authentication to login.

Comment: if you want a local /home instead of automounts, stop and disable the autofs service.  then you should be able to create home directories in /home.  don't use 777 permissions on /home.  if you want to get autofs working, that's a different question you should submit.

Answer (score -1):

Your home directory is ~
to change to your home directory

cd ~

I suspect selinux is rightfully preventing you from creating directories in /home

Home directory /home/

Comment: This is the whole issue....no home directories exist. I should be able to create home directories for users.

Comment: Upvoted back to 0 for mentioning selinux and because you're new here, but next time pls read the question more carefully

Comment: @symcbean Please do not give pity upvotes. This disrupts the site by making bad answers (and this one certainly is a bad answer: mostly irrelevant, and the rest is wrong) look ok. You are doing visitors a disservice by making them believe that this answer is useful.